# Bootstrap doesn't work properly even with jQuery file linked

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Bootstrap to make a web. I'm just using a `navbar` and a few things more. My problem here is that my dropdown and others components doesn't work properly. I added the jQuery file but it doesn't work either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">



  </head>
  <body>

    <header class="navbar" role="banner">
      <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DropTest <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="progress progress-striped active">
            <div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
              <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle sr-only" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script rel="script" href="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/McHUc/7/) with your example. Seems like everything works fine. Check your path to `bootstrap.js`

Or just try to add like this:

```
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i added the line you gave me and now it works. And even i just discovered a pretty cool tool in that "DEMO" link. I didn't know it. THANKS A LOT!